# how to update a price based on form selections

Tags: javascript, jquery

if you take a look at this site http://www.graphicfirm.com/product.php?productid=2010

see how the price changes when you select something from the select options? How is this being done?
each select looks something like this

```
<select onchange="javascript: check_options();" name="product_options[326831]" id="po326831">
<option value="564273">No</option>
<option value="564272">Yes (+ $10.00)</option>
</select>
```

what i dont understand is that the select options have a value that does not include the price that will be accumulated with the total. I'm guessing that each item such as 564272 is in an associative array with a price associated with it. can someone write me an example? i tried learning whats on that page but the javascript is really messy.  I also tried to look up a small example online and i couldnt. if you know can you link me to one? also if this method has a name let me know

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

Look in firebug or chrome, for the variable 'variants'  its got all the prices in it.  Also look for the event handlers on the input elements.  Buried in all of the nested, nested, and more nested layers are references to that array.

EDIT--

the general approach is simple

1. populate an array of option keys to prices.
2. put an event handler on the input elements.  the handler is or calls a function that updates the price.
3. write the method that updates the price.  This method will get all needed values off the inputs and do what it needs to do to update the price.

Comment: i am looking into it thanks, but i wish someone could write a shorter example.

Comment: @sarmenhbii, http://www.intranetjournal.com/corner/hoque/config-1.shtml  try that.  what specifically are you having trouble with?